# object not updated angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have my object

```
$scope.obj = {
    id : 0,
    name : 'parent',
    childs : [{
        obj_id : $scope.obj.id,
        name : 'child1',
    }, {
        obj_id : $scope.obj.id,
        name : 'child2',
    }]
}
```

if I change the ID attribute of my $scope.obj dynamically with an input it won't update the obj_id value of my child's objects.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.id" />
```

But if I add a new object within the `childs` attribute like this after having updated the $scope.obj.id value

```
$scope.obj.childs.push({
    obj_id : $scope.obj.id,
    name : 'child3',
});
```

the obj_id attribute of my recently `child` object push will have the new value of $scope.obj.id set in with the input.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign the parent object's id to the children in the array, it is the value of the id that is copied. So the ng-model on your input tag does not bind to the children's obj_id property at all.

Here is a much more thorough explanation of the problem:

[Binding to Values](http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/)

Perhaps what you need is a property on each child that references the parent object? That way you could get the parent's id from any child object.

```
$scope.obj = {
    id : 0,
    name : 'parent',
    childs : []
};
$scope.obj.childs.push({
    parent : $scope.obj,
    name : 'child1',
});
$scope.obj.childs.push({
    parent : $scope.obj,
    name : 'child2',
});
```

Comment: I agree with your second solution.
Thanks for the link it helps.